# How do I force constructor rules for not null and not empty on a string field in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I would like to add some specific business rules to enforce validation when instantiating an entity.

The entity's class has a field called 'name' of type String. I want to enforce that the name field must have at least one char of content during construction.

How would I approach handling these business rules in my model? I'd like to have it at the entity level and avoid handling this validation in a service.

Comment: With an `if()` in the constructor testing the validity of the argument? What's the problem?

Comment: I supposed I'm attempting to find the most pragmatic way of doing this in Groovy, as I'm new to the language. Using if() criteria on the constructor would be fine, but I'm hoping to confirm this is the best practice to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [GContracts](https://github.com/andresteingress/gcontracts).  Then you could declare a class `Invariant` like so:

```
@Grab('org.gcontracts:gcontracts:1.1.3')
import org.gcontracts.annotations.*

@Invariant( { name?.size() > 0 } )
class Entity {
    String name

    public Entity( String name ) {
        this.name == name
    }
}

assert new Entity( 'tim' )
assert new Entity( '' )
```

The call to `new Entity( '' )` in that example fails with:

```
org.gcontracts.ClassInvariantViolation: <class invariant> Entity

{ name?.size() > 0 }
  |     |      |
  ""    0      false
```